# How to upgrade to Drupal 8 from 7 with clean install?

Tags: 8, migrations, composer, upgrading

I currently have a Drupal 7 site that I want to install Drupal 8, but do a clean install. This means wiping away everything and starting with a new Drupal 8 instance. I have seen many articles on how to upgrade where the content types, fields, code, and other parts are migrated. However, I just want to upgrade to Drupal 8 without any migration of the content type, files, databases, and remove old directories that are not needed for Drupal 8.

How can I upgrade to Drupal 8 without any migration for a clean instance?

Comment: You don't. You just restart. On your local computer do `composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev my-directory --no-interaction`, then `cd my-directory` and add modules etc. See https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project

Comment: The way the question is worded, it sounds like you just want to build a fresh Drupal 8 site. That wouldn't be an "upgrade" or migration, but starting from scratch. If that's the case, look into leymannx's comment, and get familiar with composer if you aren't already. If you want to upgrade with the UI without migrating with drush, please reword the question.

Comment: @leymannx your steps did the trick. I was able to get a new copy of drupal 8 installed using that composer command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your situation correctly in that you just want a new Drupal 8 website without any of the content from your existing Drupal 7 website then you would just simply install Drupal 8 from scratch, as if you didn't even have an old site.

Once the new Drupal 8 website is installed you can then create/re-create any content that you'd like.